# Anime where a popular teen becomes a demon slayer

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am trying to find an anime that has a super popular teenager as a protagonist. One day that guy goes at night in his school with his friends and he gets attacked by some shadow daemons. And all of a sudden this weird stalker gay dude says that if he wants to survive the popular guy had to kiss him. He does and then the dude gets some daggers. Later on his friends also get superpowers and he meets a rich kid who also slays demons. I also remember that the anime had "Chrome" in its name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the statement in the question

> I also remember that the anime had "Chrome" in its name.

I searched on https://www.wcoanimesub.tv/ for the word "Chrome". This led me to  [*Monochrome Factor*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/3656/Monochrome_Factor) (2008).

From the Synopsis on MyAnimeList:

> The story revolves around high school student Akira Nikaido, a typical slacker living a normal life. That is, until he meets the mysterious Shirogane... Aya, a friend of Akira, forgets something in the school one night, and asks Akira to help her and go find it. He agrees, and while there, he gets attacked by a shadow monster. Shirogane convinces him that...Akira must become a "shin"- a creature of the shadow world....

In fairness, the synopsis doesn't mention kissing a "weird stalker gay dude" or daggers or his friends getting powers later but the rest of the details seem to fit.

Comment: Considering the genre is *shounen ai* (boys love), I guess it makes sense...